# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_updatedFibers')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I have ran into this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_updatedFibers')
at requestUpdateLane (react-dom.development.js:25411:23)
at updateContainer (react-dom.development.js:28810:14)
at ReactDOMHydrationRoot.render.ReactDOMRoot.render (react-dom.development.js:29309:3)
at eval (index.js:50:18)
at ./src/index.js (bundle_frontend_codes.js:2582:1)
...
```

while running the following code:

```
import * as React from "react"
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom"
import * as ReactDOMClient from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App'
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'

const history = createBrowserHistory()
const root = document.getElementById("root_dashboard_app")
if (root) {
    const root_dashboard = ReactDOMClient.createRoot(root)
    root_dashboard.render(<App history={history}/>) // <- error here.
}
```

my dependencies are:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.18.6",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
    "@jridgewell/sourcemap-codec": "^1.4.14",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.4",
    "@rollup/plugin-terser": "^0.3.0",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.3",
    "history": "^5.3.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "interpret": "^3.1.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.7.2",
    "mui": "^0.0.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.7.0",
    "react-cookies": "^0.1.1",
    "reactstrap": "^9.1.5",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^3.6.2",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "^6.5.4"
}, ...
"devDependencies": {
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1"
}
```

I found this post: https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber/issues/2134
but these solutions do not helped me. They assume it is a bug caused by mismatching versions, but this is not the case. I checked.

This is the only solution I found online.

Thanks !

**EDIT:**

In fire fox, the error is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: transition is undefined
```

** EDIT: **

In the github.com they suggest the error is a bug of a package I am not using. Really lost here ! Suggestions?

Comment: If you have a problem with a 3rd party library, raise an issue in their official support channel. There's little anybody here could do

Comment: Thanks Phil, someone in the github forum recommended stackoverflow.

Comment: do a clean install (`npm ci`).

Comment: I already did, but I'll try agin.

Answer (score 0):

GOT IT !!
in `webpack.config.js` I commented the line:

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
    alias: {
        //   'react-dom': '@hot-loader/react-dom',
    },
},
```

and it worked !